# Reordenação de dicionário, trocar valores por chaves

Tags: python, python-3.x

Eu tenho o seguinte dicionário:

```
tests_dict = {'test 1': ['Manuel', 'Mariana', 'Filipa'], 'test 2': ['Manuel', 'Filipa', 'Mariana'], 'test 3': ['Mariana', 'Manuel', 'Filipa']}
```

O que preciso, é que chaves do novo dicionário sejam os nomes das pessoas, com o test feito e o lugar (indice) onde o nome respetivo está na lista do dicionário atual, formato desejado:

```
peps_dict = {'Manuel': {'test 1': 1, 'test 2': 1, 'test 3': 2}, 'Mariana': {'test 1': 2, 'test 2': 3, 'test 3': 1}, 'Filipa': {'test 1': 3, 'test 2': 2, 'test 3': 3}}
```

Como se vê, o Manuel no test 1 ficou em primeiro no test 2 também ficou em primeiro e no test 3 ficou em segundo, estas posições têm como base o indice das listas no dicionário original, e somar 1, porque é um sistema de rank e não pode haver abaixo do primeiro lugar (0 não faz sentido)

Comment: Use ĩndices começando em 0. Se a palavra está na primeira posição, seu indice deve ser "0" e não "1".

Comment: Sim é verdade, isto é um sistema de rank é com base no indice mas o 0 equivale ao primeiro lugar, tal como coloquei no formato desejado. Vou fixar isso, desculpe o mau entendido

Comment: @jsbueno, também reparei nisso, mas segui-me pelo formato desejado, porque achei também que era isso que fazia sentido neste contexto e pela explicação do AP, "... Manuel no test 1 ficou em primeiro..."

Comment: @Miguel - claro, você tem que responder o que foi perguntado. Mas vale a pena comentar na resposta, qual a melhor forma de deixar os índices.

Comment: Concordo @jsbueno, claro que sim, quanto mais claro melhor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Então temos:

```
tests_dict = {'test 1': ['Manuel', 'Mariana', 'Filipa'], 'test 2': ['Manuel', 'Filipa', 'Mariana'], 'test 3': ['Mariana', 'Manuel', 'Filipa']}
```

Pode fazer assim:

#### 1.

Esta primeira maneira é mais didática, acho que assim percebe a lógica que está por de trás disto:

```
peps_dict = {}
for test in tests_dict:
    for indx, name in enumerate(tests_dict[test], 1): # vamos percorrer os nomes e respetivo indice em cada lista, começando em 1
        if name not in peps_dict: # se o nome ainda nao estiver presente como chave no nosso novo dionario
            peps_dict[name] = {} # vamos declara-lo como um dicionario tambem
        peps_dict[name][test] = indx # ex: peps_dict['Manuel']['test 1'] = 1, {'Manuel': {'test 1': 1}}
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÂO](http://ideone.com/cVI4WR)

#### 2.

Nesta maneira vamos importar [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), que neste caso permite que possamos excluir a verificação `if name not in peps_dict`, desta maneira não há `KeyError` no nosso novo dicionário, e cada chave (nome) por default definimos que seja um dicionário também:

```
from collections import defaultdict

peps_dict = defaultdict(dict)
for test in tests_dict:
    for indx, name in enumerate(tests_dict[test], 1):
        peps_dict[name][test] = indx
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÂO](http://ideone.com/jSJUS5)

Uma alternativa, NESTE caso, ao defaultdict é usar [setdefault](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_setdefault.htm) (Graças ao @JJoao que me lembrou desta em comentário), e assim escusa também de fazer o `import`, este método é aplicável só a dicionários:

```
peps_dict = {}
for test in tests_dict:
    for indx, name in enumerate(tests_dict[test], 1):
        peps_dict.setdefault(name,{})[test] = indx
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃo](http://ideone.com/n9Eu3w)

#### 3.

Esta ultima fiz mais pelo desafio, a lógica muda um pouco em relação à primeira. Vamos percorrer todos os nomes, juntamos todos os nomes numa só lista (`(name for listN in tests_dict.values() for name in listN)`), [generator](http://www.python-course.eu/python3_generators.php) neste caso, e adicionamos cada `n` como sendo uma chave do nosso dicionário, e depois por via de [dict compreension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) populamos-los com os valores correspondentes ({`test: tests_dict[test].index(n) + 1}`, vamos buscar o indice que o nome tem na lista original e somamos 1)

```
peps_dict = {}
names = (name for listN in tests_dict.values() for name in listN)
for n in names:
    peps_dict[n] = {test: tests_dict[test].index(n) + 1 for test in tests_dict if n in tests_dict[test]}
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](http://ideone.com/Im8CMY)

Esta ultima pode ser reduzida para:

```
names = (name for listN in tests_dict.values() for name in listN)
peps_dict = {n: {test: tests_dict[test].index(n) + 1 for test in tests_dict if n in tests_dict[test]} for n in names}
```

[DEMOSTRAÇÃO](http://ideone.com/n8D02C)

Output (`print(peps_dict)`) para os casos acima:

> {'Manuel': {'test 1': 1, 'test 2': 1, 'test 3': 2}, 'Filipa': {'test 1': 3, 'test 2': 2, 'test 3': 3}, 'Mariana': {'test 1': 2, 'test 2': 3, 'test 3': 1}}

**PS: Todo este  exercício parte do presuposto que não existem nomes iguais em cada lista, caso existam dois "Manuel" numa lista o ultimo a ser percorrido vai-se sobrepôr ao primeiro, não podem haver chaves iguais**

Comment: cool! sugestão na primeira substituir o if por `peps_dict.setdefault(name,{})
`

Comment: Obrigado @JJoao, acrescentei essa alternativa na resposta

Comment: obrigado eu: nunca me tinha lembrado de `setdefault(name,{})[...]=...`

Comment: hehe (: , @JJoao , é mais curto assim